# How to use Ripple emulator cordova

Tags: emulation

I'm using Ripple emulator cordova for the first time but I don't know how to use it.

I launched it in CMD like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oY0d2.jpg)

It gives me this screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKN92.png)

But I think it's not working, what should I do?

Then I would also like to ask how to deactivate Ripple Emulator

I thought this was enough to make it work but no